# Is there a list of Python shorthand commands for making lists, dictionaries, etc?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, collections

I know about `foo = []` being shorthand for `foo = list()` and I was wondering if there was a list of shorthand notations for creating empty dictionaries, tuples, sets, etc. I'm specifically looking for Python 3.x but either one would be useful to have.

Comment: `[]` is not shorthand. It is 'literal notation', and faster. See [Why is \[\] faster than list()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30216000)

Comment: But please go to the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) for basic questions like these. It covers all the basics, including [literal notations for data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that question, I'll have to give that a read. I also didn't know it was considered a literal (though I probably should have realized) I must be blind if I didn't see the literals in the docs.

Comment: Because the notation for containers is more complex than for strings, integers, etc, you find those defined as *displays*, in the [*Expressions* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an empty dictionary, use `{}`.
To create an empty tuple, use `()`.
There is no shortcut for an empty set.
As for the *etc.*, I don't know what else you are thinking of.