# How to Pythonically map content from one dict to another in a fail safe manner?

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping, try-except

I've got one dict from an api:

```
initial_dict = {
    "content": {
        "text":
    },
    "meta": {
        "title": "something",
        "created": "2016-03-04 15:30",
        "author": "Pete",
        "extra": {
            "a": 123,
            "b": 456
        }
    }
}
```

and I need to map this to another dict:

```
new_dict = {
    "content_text": initial_dict['content']['text'],
    "meta_title": initial_dict['meta']['title'],
    "meta_extras": {
        "time_related": {
            initial_dict['meta']['created']
        },
        "by": initial_dict['meta']['author']
    }
}
```

The problem is that not all fields are always in the initial_dict. I can of course wrap the whole creation of `new_dict` into a `try/except`, but then it would fail if one of the initial fields doesn't exist.

Is there no other way than creating a `try/except` for each and every field I add to the `new_dict`? In reality the dict is way bigger than this (about 400 key/value pairs), so this will become a mess quite fast.

Isn't there a better and more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Create a list where each entry is the from and to keys, loop through these in a single try/except

Comment: @barny - Sounds like a good idea, but I'm not sure how to construct something like that. Would you have some example code?

Comment: You could use `initial_dict.get('meta', dict()).get(key)`. By defaulting to `dict()` on the first call to `get`, you will remove the possibility of an error occurring

Comment: `maplist=[['fromkey1','fromkey2','tokey1','tokey2']]; for mapping in maplist: newdict[mapping[0]][mapping[1]] = initial_dict[mapping[3]][mapping[4]]` obviously you will also have to look for the key2 being None and in those cases only use one level of dictionary access.

Comment: @gtlambert: why use `dict()`? Use a `{}` empty dictionary instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure - I didn't actually realise that there is a difference between the two? Is there? Or is it just more readable to use `{}`?

Comment: @gtlambert: see [Why is \[\] faster than list()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30216156).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)? Instead of throwing an error, this returns `None` if the key isn't in the dictionary.

```
new_dict = {
    "content_text": initial_dict['content'].get('text'),
    "meta_title": initial_dict['meta'].get('title'),
    "meta_extras": {
        "time_related": {
            initial_dict['meta'].get('created')
        },
        "by": initial_dict['meta'].get('author')
    }
}
```

If this goes deeper than one level, you can do `some_dict.get('key1', {}).get('key2')` as was suggested in the comments.

Converting the original dict to a `defaultdict` is also an option, which allows you to keep using the `[]` notation (more practical than having to chain `get` methods):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def to_defaultdict(d):
    return defaultdict(lambda: None, ((k, to_defaultdict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v)
                                      for k, v in d.items()))
initial_dict = to_defaultdict(initial_dict)
```

You can then filter out the `None` values:

```
def filter_dict(d):
    return dict((k, filter_dict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v)
                for k, v in d.items() if v is not None)
new_dict = filter_dict(new_dict)
```