# getting only integers from a list of tuples python 3

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-3.5

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[(a,3), (b, 4), (c, 5), (d, 1), (e,2)]
```

and I'd like to extract a list like this from it:

```
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

How would I go about this? I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Readability is secondary to speed in this context, as this code will be tucked away in a relatively well commented function.

Comment: `[i[-1] for i in lst]`

Comment: Do you need the whole list loaded or do you have memory constraints as well?

Comment: If you decide which answer you use, accept and upvote it. Don't edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @LutzHorn Then he needs to upvote my comment :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry :) Care to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If goal is efficiency, let's look at the different methods:

```
from timeit import timeit
from operator import itemgetter

T = [('a',3), ('b', 4), ('c', 5), ('d', 1), ('e',2)] 

def one():
    [v for _, v in T]

def two():
    [v[-1] for v in T]

def three():
    list(map(itemgetter(1), T))

def four():
    list(map(lambda x:x[1], T))

def five():
    list(zip(*T))[1]

for func in (one, two, three, four, five):
    print(func.__name__ + ':', timeit(func))
```

Results:

```
one: 0.8771702060003008
two: 1.0403959849991224
three: 1.5230304799997612
four: 1.9551190909996876
five: 1.3489514130005773
```

So, the first one seems to be more efficient.
Note that use tuple instead of list change the ranks, but is slower [for `one` and `two`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list?rq=1):

```
one: 1.620873247000418  # slower
two: 1.7368736420003188  # slower
three: 1.4523903099998279
four: 1.9480371049994574
five: 1.2643559589996585
```

Answer (score 0):

Generators for the win:

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = [(a,3), (b, 4), (c, 5), (d, 1), (e,2)]
r = map(itemgetter(1), l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tuples = [(a,3), (b, 4), (c, 5), (d, 1), (e,2)]
```

If every time numbers on second position:

```
numbers = [item[1] for item in tuples]
```

Elif number is integer:

```
numbers = [value for item in tuples for value in item if isinstance(value, int)]
```

Elif number is string like '3':

```
numbers = [value for item in tuples for value in item if isinstance(value, str) and value.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it with `zip`:

```
>>> l = [('a',3), ('b', 4), ('c', 5), ('d', 1), ('e',2)]
>>> list(zip(*l))[1]
(3, 4, 5, 1, 2)
```

If you really need a *list* instead of a *tuple*:

```
>>> list(list(zip(*l))[1])
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> map(lambda x:x[1], lst)
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

In python 3, do:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x:x[1], lst))
```