# Why is it possible to replace sometimes set() with {}?

Tags: python, set

In PyCharm, when I write:

```
return set([(sy + ady, sx + adx)])
```

it says *"Function call can be replaced with set literal"* so it replaces it with:

```
return {(sy + ady, sx + adx)}
```

Why is that? A `set()` in Python is not the same as a dictionary `{}`?

And if it wants to optimize this, why is this more effective?

Comment: Note that, despite your title, you **cannot** replace `set()` with `{}`, but you *can* replace a non-empty `set((1, 2, 3))` with a literal `{1, 2, 3}`, because now it's clear that's not a dictionary. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Python sets and dictionaries can both be constructed using curly braces:

`my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

`my_set = {1, 2, 3}`

The interpreter (and human readers) can distinguish between them based on their contents.  However it isn't possible to distinguish between an empty set and an empty dict, so this case you need to use `set()` for empty sets to disambiguate.

A very simple test suggests that the literal construction is faster (python3.5):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a = set([1, 2, 3])')
0.5449375328607857
>>> timeit.timeit('a = {1, 2, 3}')
0.20525191631168127
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list) covers some issues of performance of literal constructions over builtin functions, albeit for lists and dicts. The summary seems to be that literal constructions require less work from the interpreter.

Comment: The literal construction is probably faster because you don't build an intermediate list; what if you factor that out?

Comment: @jonrsharpe still seems slower: `timeit.timeit(stmt='a = set(mylist)', setup='mylist=[1, 2, 3]') -> 0.3987466390244663` - I think the link I added covers some of this.

Comment: Wow in Python3.8, trying your tests, the difference is impressive: `0.1970` vs `0.0705`

Answer (score 9):

It is an alternative syntax for `set()`

```
>>> a = {1, 2}
>>> b = set()
>>> b.add(1)
>>> b.add(2)
>>> b
set([1, 2])
>>> a
set([1, 2])
>>> a == b
True
>>> type(a) == type(b)
True
```

`dict` syntax is different. It consists of key-value pairs. For example:

```
my_obj = {1:None, 2:None}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another example how `set` and `{}` are **not interchangeable** (as jonrsharpe mentioned):

```
In: f = 'FH'

In: set(f)
Out: {'F', 'H'}

In: {f}
Out: {'FH'}
```

Comment: Functionality of `set(f)` with literals must use unpacking: `{*f}`.

Comment: It's never possible to replace `set(somestuff)` with `{somestuff}`. But it is possible to replace `set([somestuff])` with `{somestuff}` whenever `somestuff` is not literally 0 characters in your source code. Since OP was using `set([somestuff])` and `somestuff` wasn't 0 characters, that's why the replacement was possible.

Answer (score 4):

`set([iterable])` is the constructor to create a set from the optional iterable `iterable`. And `{}` is to create set / dict object literals. So what is created depends on how you use it.

```
In [414]: x = {}

In [415]: type(x)
Out[415]: dict

In [416]: x = {1}

In [417]: type(x)
Out[417]: set

In [418]: x = {1: "hello"}

In [419]: type(x)
Out[419]: dict
```

Comment: When you say `set([iterable])` do you mean the literal characters `[` and `]` show up? Or are you using ABNF to indicate that `iterable` is an optional parameter to the function `set()`? Because the first case is wrong, the second case it correct. It's quite confusing because many people will read this and think you mean the first case.