# How to check if a Pandas row contains an empty set

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I want to check if a Pandas Dataframe row contains an empty set in a specific column, i.e.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, {}]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


    col1    col2
0   1       3
1   2       {}
```

and then

```
df2['col_2_contains_empty_set'] = ? #  how to implement this
```

should give

```
    col1    col2    col_2_contains_empty_set
0   1       3       False
1   2       {}      True
```

What's the correct way to do this? Can't do

```
bool(df['col2'])
```

or

```
df['col2'].bool()
```

as `Series` are have ambiguous Boolean values, I think.

Comment: That's a `dict`, not a `set`.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for the point; I checked and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674083/why-is-it-possible-to-replace-set-with/36674133 seems to confirm that, in fact, sets *can* be declared like that.

Comment: Sets, yes, but not empty sets. Run `print(type({}))`, compared to `print(type({1}))`.

Comment: @Sebastian Well, that's that then :) thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6):

One way:

```
df2.apply(lambda x: any(x.values == {}), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

OR

```
df2['c'] = np.max(df2.values == {}, 1).astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2      c
0     1    3  False
1     2   {}   True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that len({})=0 and apply a lambda function:

```
df2['col2'].apply(lambda x: len(x)==0)
```

Note that this will return True for empty lists and dicts as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can just compare `df2.values` to an empty dictionary:

```
In [ ]: df2['col_2_contains_empty_set'] = (df2.values == {}).any(axis=1)
   ...: df2
Out[ ]: 
   col1 col2  col_2_contains_empty_set
0     1    3                     False
1     2   {}                      True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2.applymap(type)==type({})
Out[1044]: 
    col1   col2
0  False  False
1  False   True
```

after assgin it back

```
df2['C']=(df2.applymap(type)==type({})).any(1)
df2
Out[1052]: 
   col1 col2      C
0     1    3   False
1     2   {}    True
```