# Why is `{*l}` faster than `set(l)` - python sets (not really only for sets, for all sequences)

Tags: python, set, sequence, timing, unpack

So here is my timings:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: set(l))
0.7210583936611334
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: {*l})
0.5386332845236943
```

Why is that, my opinion would be equal but it's not.

So unpacking is fast from this example, right?

Comment: The identifier `set` could be redefined so it needs an additional dictionary lookup but this would probably not explain the whole difference.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks you for the comment, helped me :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the same reason [`[]` is faster than `list()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30216000/364696); the interpreter includes dedicated support for syntax based operations that uses specialized code paths, while constructor calls involve:

1. Loading the constructor from built-in scope (requires a pair of `dict` lookups, one in global scope, then another in built-in scope when it fails)
2. Requires dispatch through generic callable dispatch mechanisms, and generic argument parsing code, all of which is far more expensive than a single byte code that reads all of its arguments off the stack as a C array

All of these advantages relate to *fixed* overhead; the big-O of both approaches are the same, so `{*range(10000)}` won't be noticeably/reliably faster than `set(range(10000))`, because the actual construction work vastly outweighs the overhead of loading and calling the constructor via generic dispatch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `[]` is faster than `list()` too, wow good explanation, only can accept in 8 minutes.