# Improve speed performance of a python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

The function `transform_input` does the following:

- The `combination` parameter is a list of tuples (the size of this list is usually maxed at 6) containing 1 or 2 values.
- It then removes all redundancy inside `combination`. What I call redundancy is to remove duplicates and to remove tuples that contains the same values swapped. Examples of redundant tuples: `(2,3) and (3,2)`, `(7,) and (7,)`, `(1,2) and (1,2)`.
- The resulting tuple **must** be in ascending order. Example: `(2,4)` and not `(4,2)`.
- The order of the resulting list is not important.
- All tuple values are positive integers.

The code I came up with is the one below (with a running example):

```
def transform_input(combination):
  combination = [list(elem) for elem in combination]
  for t in combination:
      t.sort()
  combination = [tuple(elem) for elem in combination]
  combination = list(set(combination))
  return combination

my_input = [
[(3,8), (8,3), (7,)],
[(8,8), (8,8)],
[(3,), (7,), (6,), (3,), (7,)],
[(2,3), (3,2)],
[(2,), (2,)]
]

for comb in my_input:
  print(transform_input(comb))
```

The output is:

```
[(3, 8), (7,)]
[(8, 8)]
[(6,), (7,), (3,)]
[(2, 3)]
[(2,)]
```

Is there a way that I can improve the speed performance of `transform_input`?

This piece of code is executed a lot in my real program, every improvement would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here two other possible approaches; the first is a slight variation of the answer posted by [Błotosmętek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61560019/5359797), using `{}` rather than `set` (it should be faster on lists with very few elements, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53219691/5359797) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53978015/5359797)).

```
def transform_input3(combination):
    return list({tuple(sorted(elem)) for elem in combination})
```

The other approach is based on the `map` function (i.e., using iterators).

```
def transform_input4(combination):
    return list(set(map(tuple, map(sorted, combination))))
```

If the inner tuples cannot contain more than 2 elements, you can implement something like this to avoid sorting each of them and conversion from `list` to `tuple`:

```
def transform_input6(combination):
    return [t for t in {x[::-1] if x[0] > x[-1] else x for x in combination}]
```

I added some items to your `my_input` (and the one used by [alireza yazdandoost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561060/5359797)) and benchmarked all the approaches, running every function 100 times on each item; this is the new `my_input`:

```
my_input = [
    [(3, 8), (8, 3), (7,)],
    [(3, 8), (8, 3), (7,), (3, 8), (8, 3), (7,)],
    [(8, 8), (8, 8)],
    [(3,), (7,), (6,)],
    [(3,), (7,), (6,), (3,), (7,), (3,)],
    [(2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2)],
    [(2,), (2,)],
    [(2,), (2,), (2,), (2,), (2,), (2,)],
    [(3, 8), (8, 3), (7,), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3)],
    [(3, 8), (8, 3), (7,), (3, 4), (8, 8), (8, 8), (3,), (7,), (6,), (3,), (7,), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2,), (2,)],
]
```

These are the results of the benchmark (`my_transform` is your original code, `my_transform2` is Błotosmętek's answer and `my_transform5` is alireza yazdandoost's answer), as mean and standard deviation of the execution time (in sec):

```
[(3, 8), (8, 3), (7,)]
transform_input: 2.524e-06 (9.738e-07)
transform_input2: 2.067e-06 (2.728e-07)
transform_input3: 1.750e-06 (1.570e-07)
transform_input4: 1.804e-06 (1.984e-07)
transform_input5: 1.116e-06 (2.566e-07)
transform_input6: 1.051e-06 (1.874e-07)

[(3, 8), (8, 3), (7,), (3, 8), (8, 3), (7,)]
transform_input: 3.743e-06 (2.239e-07)
transform_input2: 3.308e-06 (2.461e-07)
transform_input3: 2.893e-06 (1.354e-07)
transform_input4: 2.848e-06 (9.448e-07)
transform_input5: 1.710e-06 (2.458e-07)
transform_input6: 1.477e-06 (1.823e-07)

[(8, 8), (8, 8)]
transform_input: 1.894e-06 (2.101e-07)
transform_input2: 1.641e-06 (1.979e-07)
transform_input3: 1.370e-06 (1.294e-07)
transform_input4: 1.593e-06 (1.063e-06)
transform_input5: 9.250e-07 (2.063e-07)
transform_input6: 8.319e-07 (1.358e-07)

[(3,), (7,), (6,)]
transform_input: 2.415e-06 (1.107e-06)
transform_input2: 1.944e-06 (2.173e-07)
transform_input3: 1.635e-06 (1.073e-07)
transform_input4: 1.710e-06 (1.585e-07)
transform_input5: 1.079e-06 (1.747e-07)
transform_input6: 1.061e-06 (9.636e-07)

[(3,), (7,), (6,), (3,), (7,), (3,)]
transform_input: 3.653e-06 (1.049e-06)
transform_input2: 3.152e-06 (2.191e-07)
transform_input3: 2.749e-06 (1.331e-07)
transform_input4: 2.576e-06 (1.495e-07)
transform_input5: 1.674e-06 (2.078e-07)
transform_input6: 1.285e-06 (1.356e-07)

[(2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2)]
transform_input: 6.527e-06 (2.066e-07)
transform_input2: 5.980e-06 (2.107e-07)
transform_input3: 5.370e-06 (1.381e-07)
transform_input4: 5.504e-06 (4.534e-06)
transform_input5: 2.974e-06 (1.017e-06)
transform_input6: 2.422e-06 (1.929e-07)

[(2,), (2,)]
transform_input: 1.830e-06 (1.616e-07)
transform_input2: 1.565e-06 (2.068e-07)
transform_input3: 1.317e-06 (1.332e-07)
transform_input4: 1.541e-06 (1.074e-06)
transform_input5: 9.414e-07 (1.911e-07)
transform_input6: 8.253e-07 (1.391e-07)

[(2,), (2,), (2,), (2,), (2,), (2,)]
transform_input: 3.798e-06 (1.423e-06)
transform_input2: 3.165e-06 (2.080e-07)
transform_input3: 2.767e-06 (1.471e-07)
transform_input4: 2.602e-06 (1.492e-07)
transform_input5: 1.718e-06 (2.056e-07)
transform_input6: 1.255e-06 (1.435e-07)

[(3, 8), (8, 3), (7,), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3)]
transform_input: 3.762e-06 (2.038e-07)
transform_input2: 3.323e-06 (2.212e-07)
transform_input3: 2.923e-06 (1.341e-07)
transform_input4: 2.763e-06 (1.599e-07)
transform_input5: 1.663e-06 (2.349e-07)
transform_input6: 1.468e-06 (1.796e-07)

[(3, 8), (8, 3), (7,), (3, 4), (8, 8), (8, 8), (3,), (7,), (6,), (3,), (7,), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2,), (2,)]
transform_input: 7.692e-06 (3.647e-07)
transform_input2: 7.048e-06 (2.708e-07)
transform_input3: 6.550e-06 (1.439e-06)
transform_input4: 6.143e-06 (2.281e-06)
transform_input5: 3.450e-06 (2.875e-07)
transform_input6: 2.544e-06 (2.064e-07)
```

[Here](https://tio.run/##rVbbrqMgFH33K8i8VBOmORV1mmY6nzA/0BhDWzqHjKIRnLRp@u0dkLbeD5jUB0H2Yq3FdqMUF/GZM3S/OzQr8lIAVmXFBWAOWPEcEjQjVDjOqcwzcKrYQeR5ysEjWpJjdSCO4xzJCYgSM37KyyyhrKiEe8izPWVY0Jx5GwfIqzUCtmCXUi5ckpLMA3IaUD1AWRsV19NUUPQimlBdYsmlFdcbUxBVkRIbie682hgn3SVogZKIquwQjK/eH1n@Y@6LXbtT7slRm5x0KdVHZZBB5jpD4zahEVgsJcOFXg4Eqqv1YHcFU2sIR/g/Mf8UeJ8S@TauN4sqKMk/CRW7zeb7Kn6N0lMdkJNehM2UB0DsPmLwU@FkpxvtONm5CgklfhV7sRT7nTPSgZOUkyHBIWeCsqqBDmGNhugQt7P8wiz/kgt3p5IZTb@snWhyeD3rTKkEnFUCfslGPStz4FwDz/36iKWkxCcJwxlJErDdgkWSZJiyJFloqeyibajN91rizkUQrD0I3DUESLU/oBfDr@Pybpq1buLrPl/DEsEvY7VOW7OL9h/a0ouv2rc@95R0fGJ06m6Rx1EPdvkPXvlttV9ncKj2dFoLyiJ67mZVW6rGnkXTbIqipOz5SVcX5pzI3w3llHGB2YG4o59bKaT2igcwO4LHN28c6KniHUc8APbayFYbvV87sNUO3q8d2mqH79eObLWj2dq69urB5oyxUj@X@ii0LElBsHC/jdJ8g@BPmu9xyrfXhRpZbOoyh2DRw8tAb@QGgeberj4@oDqM7Um5XbVc@EYX/lwb/tCHbzaCjEbQXCNoaASZjQRGI8FcI8HQSGA2EhqNhHONhEMjodlIZDQSzTUSDY1ERiN6G/WpNuC6WSJyA65uvcVSBaVLViwzgpkrVnJXywcujqrvmRh9C0q/RembKZEFJWpRIjNlYEEZtCgDM2VoQRm2KEMzZWRBGbUoI32md5z7/T8) you can find the code used to produce the results and you can play with it.

Comment: very good, I think you have just forgotten to cast the final response to the list.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot @PieCot

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit more efficient (not sure, check):

```
def transform_input(combination):
  return list(set([tuple(sorted(elem)) for elem in combination]))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know tuples are hashable, so you can use them as `dict` keys.

As you may know, inserting to and searching in hashtables is done in O(1) order.

So using a hashtable(`dict` in python) may help your code to be improved.

I wrote the `transform_input2` based on the above facts.

I know It's not very well readable but it enhanced the performance.

*I changed your code a bit to be able to calculate the elapsed time in each solution better.

```py
import time

def transform_input3(combination):
    print("start")
    start = time.time()
    res = list(set([tuple(sorted(elem)) for elem in combination]))
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
    return res


def transform_input2(combination):
    print("start")
    start = time.time()
    hashtable = {}
    for t in combination:
        rev = t[::-1]
        if rev in hashtable:
            if t[0]<rev[0]:
                hashtable[(t[0],t[1])] = None
            else:
                continue
        else:
            hashtable[t] = None
    res = list(hashtable.keys())    
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
    return res

def transform_input(combination):
    print("start")
    start = time.time()
    combination = [list(elem) for elem in combination]
    for t in combination:
        t.sort()
    combination = [tuple(elem) for elem in combination]
    combination = list(set(combination))
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
    return combination

my_input = [
(3,8), (8,3), (7,), (3,4),
(8,8), (8,8),
(3,), (7,), (6,), (3,), (7,),
(2,3), (3,2),
(2,), (2,)
]
print(transform_input(my_input))
print(transform_input2(my_input))
print(transform_input3(my_input))
```

here is the result for one execution:

```
start
3.600120544433594e-05
[(2,), (3,), (3, 8), (8, 8), (2, 3), (6,), (7,), (3, 4)]
start
1.0967254638671875e-05
[(3, 8), (7,), (3, 4), (8, 8), (3,), (6,), (2, 3), (2,)]
start
1.9788742065429688e-05
[(2,), (3,), (3, 8), (8, 8), (2, 3), (6,), (7,), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me out!

Comment: @ihavenoidea no problem :)