# Modifying output of for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am looping in through a file as per the code below:

```
for i in tree.iter():
    for j in i:
        print(j.col)
        print(j.out)
        print('\n')
```

Given below is the current output:

```
col1
out1

col2
out2

col3
out3
```

I am trying to have this modified as below:

```
col1,col2,col3
out1,out2,out3
```

Could anyone advice on how I could have my for loop modified. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
print(j.col, end=',')
```

Edit:
By default Python adds an "\n" new line break at the end of print() functions.
You can use the "end" value to change it.

I've made a makeshift version of your code to test it out

```
j = 0
k = 0

while j < 2:
    print("col", end=",")
    if j == 1:
        print("col")
    j += 1

while k < 2:
    print("out", end=",")
    if k == 1:
        print("out")
    k += 1
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I added a new line at the end of each loop and have updated my initial post.. This now gives an empty break before starting the loop.. Still trying to see how I could write new row after each empty row as a new column

Comment: I'm still new with python, but I'd do it with two loops, one for col, one for out and also add the "end" value from my answer. I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3.x**: save `cols` and `outs` into two separate lists and later print their elements (using an asterisk before the list name) separated by a comma:

```
cols = list()
outs = list()

for i in tree.iter():
    for j in i:
        cols.append(j.col)
        outs.append(j.out)
    print(*cols, sep=',')
    print(*outs, sep=',')
```

Comment: Is there a different between `list()` and `[]` or it's just a matter of preference? What does the asterisk do?

Comment: `list()` is calling a function, while `[]` is a literal syntax. The second option is slightly faster, but unless you're creating a million of lists the difference will not be noticeable and can be a matter of preference ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list) some explanation of the time difference). Asterisk in front of a list acts as unpack operator, so it will expand the list into arguments that are passed into the print function.