# Why can we explicitly call list() with only one argument, but can pass multiple arguments to []?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When creating lists in python, the two easy methods are `list(arg)` and `[args]`. However, only one of these allows multiple arguments, even though both result in an object of type `list`. Example:

```
>>> a=list('foo')
>>> type(a)
<class 'list'>
>>> a=list('foo','bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
>>> a=['foo','bar']
>>> a
['foo', 'bar']
>>> type(a)
<class 'list'>
```

Why is only the implicit call to `list()` via brackets valid?

Comment: `[]` is not a function, you aren't passing arguments to it. It is part of a list-literal, and even if it were a function, it works differently than `list`. `[]` is **not** and implicit call to `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets enclose a [list display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) (AKA list literal), and there is no implicit call to `list()`.

- Related: [Why is [] faster than list()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30216000/4518341)

[`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) takes only one argument because it expects an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). For example in `list('foo')`, the output is `['f', 'o', 'o']`, not `['foo']`.

Answer (score 0):

The `list` constructor is designed for two cases: to only accept an empty argument and return a new empty list, or to accept an `iterable` that will be expanded into a list of the separate items within the iterable.

A single string is an iterable, but two strings separated by a comma is not, so:

```
>>> list('foo')
['f', 'o', 'o']

>>> help(list)
Help on class list in module builtins:

class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
...
```