# Create multiple dictionaries in an efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have to create more than 10 dictionaries. Is there a more efficient way to create multiple dictionaries using Python's built-in libraries as described below:

```
    dict1_1= {
    "value":100,
    "secondvalue":200,
    "thirdvalue":300
}
dict1_2= {
    "fixedvalue":290,
    "changedvalue":180,
    "novalue":0
}
```

Comment: Why do you think what you've written is inefficient?  It's pretty much what any Python programmer would write.

Comment: Ohhh. I was thinking if I can create multiple dictionaries like this using loops.

Comment: Is there some similarity between your dictionaries?  Why do you think a loop would help?

Comment: yes you are right! By the way is there any other way to assign it so that it will look more presentable?

Answer (score 1):

The [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) builtin will create a dictionary from keyword arguments:

```
>>> dict(a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

but you can use integers as keyword arguments:

```
>>> dict(a=1, 2=2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    dict(a=1, 2=2)
              ^^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

However, `dict` will also accept an iterable of key/value tuples, and in this case they keys may be integers

```
>>> dict([('a', 1), (2, 2)])
{'a': 1, 2: 2}
```

If your keys are the same for all dicts you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> keys = ('a', 2)
>>> values = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>> for vs in values:
...     print(dict(zip(keys, vs)))
... 
{'a': 1, 2: 2}
{'a': 3, 2: 4}
```

However, if your keys are not consistent, there's nothing wrong with using the literal `{...}` constructor.  In fact, if it's efficiency that you want, the literal constructor may be the [best choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple function to create new dictionaries. Look at the code below:

```
func = lambda **kwargs: kwargs

my_dict = func(x="test", y=1, z=[1, 'test'])
```

- Note that the keys of dictionary can only be string

Comment: Thanks. However, I also have integers for the keys.

Comment: The [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) builtin already does the same as `func`.