# c++ is "Getting element at index from list" or "Getting element at index of vector", faster

Tags: c++, performance, vector, iterator

As you know, there are many options for grouping objects in `c++` but each of them has cons and pros, but for now, I am only talking about `Lists` and `Vectors`.

So, Which one *(`List` and `Vector`)* to choose when **`Getting an Element at index`** is under pressure *(called more (A lot of times))*

> **The decision must depend on the performance**

**|** For example, Lists must have iterators:

```cpp
std::list<std::string>::iterator it = listOfStrs.begin();

std::advance(it, 2);
```

**|** And Vectors can be directly used with an operator:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vecOfNums{ 1, 4, 5, 22, 33, 2, 11, 89, 49 };

int & element = vecOfNums[3];
```

**In a nutshell, the question is** `Which method of getting an element from an index is faster?`

*A relative question for phyton: [Why is [] faster than list()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list)*

**Explanation for my case so the question doesn't become an XY question:**

> Well, as it is really obvious I am trying to iterate through a group of elements/objects, these objects are Classes that are defined in a header file...
> I am using These classes to indicate Commands because I am making my own programming language and to do this I need a compiler as it is reallllllyy obvious I need to iterate through the commands and I just need to know which method is faster Lists or Vectors

**Edit:**

I want to iterate through the whole group so not a random element

Comment: Anytime you have to iterate a linked list to find data, which you pretty much always have to do if you access linked list by index, you're taking a performance hit, usually a significant one, over random access.

Comment: Your question initially seems different from what the last paragraph asks for. There is a difference between the indexing a random element of the container and iterating over the whole container in order. Which of the two are you interested in? And for iterating in order you wouldn't use `std::advance`.

Comment: Handy reading: [Are lists evil?](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists)

Comment: Note that C++ lists and Python lists have nothing in common except the name.

Comment: @MarkRansom I linked that for the users that can accidently come here while searching for phyton should I better remove it?

Comment: The linked duplicate answers the question for iterating in-order (rather than random access).

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks I literally didn't see the duplicate post after writing my question I event checked twice sorry for that

Comment: Isn't this a basic data structures issue?  Arrays can use math to access any slot in the data structure.  A linked list has to follow the links to find items.  So, to access item 5 in an array: pointer = array_base + 5 * sizeof(element).  A linked list must traverse through 4 nodes to get to the element; because we don't know where in memory the nodes are.