# IndexError: list assignment index out of range - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with my code, I just want to write the result in csv and i got `IndexError`

```
seleksi = []
p = FeatureSelection(fiturs, docs)

seleksi[0] = p.select()
with open('test.csv','wb') as selection:
    selections = csv.writer(selection)
    for x in seleksi:
        selections.writerow(selections)
```

In p.select is:

```
['A',1]
['B',2]
['C',3]
etc
```

and i got error in:

```
seleksi[0] = p.select()
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what should i do?

Comment: What does this line do `seleksi[0] = p.select()` ?

Answer (score 1):

`[]`, calls `__get(index)` in background. when you say `seleksi[0]`, you are trying to get value at index `0` of `seleksi`, which is an empty list.

You should just do:

```
seleksi = p.select()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accesing before assignment on `seleksi[0] = p.select()`, this should solve it:

```
seleksi.append(p.select())
```

Since you are iterating over `saleksi` I guess that what you really want is to store `p.select()`, you may want to do `seleksi = p.select()` instead then.

**EDIT:**

> i got this selections.writerow(selections) _csv.Error: sequence
>   expected

you want to write `x`, so `selections.writerow(x)` is the way to go.

Your final code would look like this:

```
p = FeatureSelection(fiturs, docs)

seleksi = p.select()
with open('test.csv','wb') as selection:
    selections = csv.writer(selection)
    for x in seleksi:
        selections.writerow(x)
```

Comment: and i got this `selections.writerow(selections)
_csv.Error: sequence expected` @Netwave

Comment: @RozBarb, i think you want to write `x`, so `selections.writerow(x)`

Comment: when i add the code like this
`seleksi.append(p.select())
with open('test.csv','wb') as selection:
    selections = csv.writer(selection)
    for x in seleksi:
        selections.writerow(x)`

it's just write index[0] @Netwave

Answer (score 0):

When you initlialize a list using

```
seleksi = []
```

It is an empty list. The lenght of list is 0. 
Hence

```
seleksi[0]
```

gives an error.

You need to append to the list for it to get values, something like

```
seleksi.append(p.select())
```

If you still want to assign it based on index, initialize it as array of zeros or some dummy value

```
seleksi = [0]* n
```

See this: [List of zeros in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528178/list-of-zeros-in-python)