# Python3 list filled with empty dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found the [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528178/list-of-zeros-in-python) to make a list filled with the same literal.

So I did following:

```
my_list_of_dict = [{}] * 3

my_list_of_dict[0][0] = 1
my_list_of_dict[0][1] = 2

print(my_list_of_dict)
# What I thought : [{0: 1, 1: 2}, {}, {}]
# What actually happened : [{0: 1, 1: 2}, {0: 1, 1: 2}, {0: 1, 1: 2}]
```

Is this a bug? or an intended feature?

It seems like python doesn't initialize new dict every time but just assigning given dict to the list.

Plus, How do I `call(pronouce) [] * n`? is this a kind of list comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{}` returns a reference to the dict, and then by `*3` you are making 3 references to the same `dict`.
To fix this, use a different approach:

```
[{} for _ in range(3)]
```

With `zeros` (`0`) it doesnt matter because they are inmutable so once you modify the value inside the list you are "creating" a new number and then reference it through the list:

```
>>> l = [0]*3
>>> [id(x) for x in l]
[10910368, 10910368, 10910368]
>>> l[0] = 10
>>> [id(x) for x in l]
[10910688, 10910368, 10910368]
```

But with mutable objects you are modifiying the object referenced directly, so all the positions in the list are aware of that change, since they point to the same object:

```
>>> l = [[]]*3
>>> l
[[], [], []]
>>> l[0].append(10)
>>> l
[[10], [10], [10]]
>>> [id(x) for x in l]
[139858640463368, 139858640463368, 139858640463368]
```

By using the other comprehension, you are creating a **new** instance in each loop of the comprehension:

```
>>> l = [{} for _ in range(3)]
>>> l[0]["foo"] = 10
>>> l
[{'foo': 10}, {}, {}]
```

Comment: Got it! thanks a lot, and can I know how do I say `[] * n` thing? list multipication? list comprehension? list construnction?

Comment: @Jerry, I do not remember how to call that, sorry!